# eck entity reference field not displaying custom fields

Tags: views, 8, entities

I created two entities using eck module, entities A and B.

Entity A has text field and I want it to be searchable and displayed in entity reference autocomplete.

I created *entity reference* view for entity A, and I set my custom field to be searchable.
In view preview, content is normally displayed.

Entity B has entity reference field, where I target entity A.

I edited reference field by setting:

***Reference Type*** -> *Reference Method*: Views: Filter by an entity reference view

And ***View used to select the entities***: ENTITY_A_reference_view - Entity reference

Now in entity B add/edit form I'm using autocomplete widget, and search works, but display doesn't.

All I'm getting is ID.

[image: no desc]
(other widgets are empty as well)

I guess it's because it's still using only ID and Title fields for display, and I'm not using title as property so it's empty.

So how can I display custom fields instead of default?

Comment: [This is a known Drupal 8 Views Entity Reference bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Drupal 8 bug.

Comment: @NoSssweat Alright, thanks!

Also, I see now that it was discussed [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198944/how-to-show-multiple-inline-fields-in-entity-reference-inline-fields-in-views)

Comment: and [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201641/how-to-change-the-autocomplete-for-a-user-reference-to-show-first-last-name-inst/201653#201653)